# PHP Namespace qualification - why do I have to fully qualify?

Tags: php, namespaces

I am converting from c# to php and I'm having trouble transitioning in some places. Particularly namespaces. The problem I am having is I have to fully qualify every namespace when calling a class from another namespace. Is this normal?

```
<?php
    namespace Lib\Things;

    class TheThings
    {

    }
```

then in the other class

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Lib\Things;

    class DoStuff
    {
        public function doStuff()
        {
            $things = new TheThings();
        }
    }
```

That doesn't work... I end up having to do

```
new Lib\Things\TheThings();
```

Or

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Lib\Things as T;

    class DoStuff
    {
        public function doStuff()
        {
            $things = new T\TheThings();
        }
    }
```

I've also got this in my composer.json file

```
"psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Lib\\": "lib/"
    }
```

Is that normal or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: treat namespaces like a directory path. if you're in the `foo\bar` namespace, then `new Baz()` is going to try to instantiate `foo\bar\Baz`. it's not going to scan the entire system to see if there's a `Baz` in some other namespace. if you don't use absolute paths for namespaces or directories, they're RELATIVE paths, and you have to adjust for where you are.

Comment: Unlike many other languages, you can't import a namespace/package and  access the simple class names directly =(

so you have to either:
```use Acme\Foo;
new Foo\Bar();
```
or
```use Acme\Foo\Bar;
new Bar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.importing.php) the `use` keyword is referred to as importing or *aliasing*.
This means that

```
use Lib\Things;
```

and

```
use Lib\Things as Things;
```

are the same. This results that you don't have to use the fully qualified names to instantiate classes from a namespace, you can use only the alias of the imported namespace. So in your case, the following would have worked:

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Lib\Things;
    // same as:
    // use Lib\Things as Things; // explicit alias

    class DoStuff
    {
        public function doStuff()
        {
            $things = new Things\TheThings();
        }
    }
```

(Note that this is the same as your second example, the only difference is that the alias is not explicitly set here to `T` (and defaults to `Things`).

To be able to use the class name without any namespace prefix, you will have to set the alias of the actual class:

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Lib\Things\TheThings;
    // same as:
    // use Lib\Things\TheThings as TheThings; // explicit alias

    class DoStuff
    {
        public function doStuff()
        {
            $things = new TheThings();
        }
    }
```

In conclusion, if you start thinking about the `use` operator as setting an alias for a namespace or class (or other), you will get the hang of it.

PS 1:

Before PHP 7, if you wanted to import multiple classes from the same namespace, you had to write:

```
use some\namespace\ClassA;
use some\namespace\ClassB;
use some\namespace\ClassC as C;
```

> From PHP 7.0 onwards, classes, functions and constants being imported from the same namespace can be grouped together in a single use statement:

```
use some\namespace\{ClassA, ClassB, ClassC as C};
```

PS 2:

composer helps in *automagically* including/loading the actual php files, based on some PSR* rule, it does not have any role in how namespaces work in bare PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
$things = new TheThings();
```

Class is searched on the current namespace (`App` in your example), thats why not worked.

So, you need to specify full class namespace, so interpreter know which class are you refering, you could also have a `namepsace2/TheThings` and `this/is/another/namespace/TheThings` classes.

Just include full class namespace

```
use Lib\Things\TheThings;
```